# listbox com registros do banco

Tags: c#, mysql, uwp

Com esse código crio um item na listbox com o numero do id, gostaria de que ele criasse um item para cada registro de id que tem no banco. Banco: Mysql Codigo: UWP C#

```
 using (_connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("Database=roubo_furto; Data Source=localhost;User Id=test;Password=1234;SslMode=None;"))
        {
            System.Text.EncodingProvider ppp;
            ppp = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);

            _connection.Open();
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT id FROM teste", _connection);

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {

                    listBox.Items.Add(("Registro: " +reader.GetString("id")));


                }
            }
        }
```

Como fazer para que não adicione um item do regitro novamente quando ja ouver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primeiro você tem que trocar o IF por WHILE para passar por todos os registros, e para não inserir registros repetidos sua consulta deve trazer somente registros não repetidos, usando a palavra chave DISTINCT.

```
using (_connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("Database=roubo_furto; Data Source=localhost;User Id=test;Password=1234;SslMode=None;"))
        {
            System.Text.EncodingProvider ppp;
            ppp = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
            Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);

            _connection.Open();
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT distinct id FROM teste", _connection);

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    listBox.Items.Add(("Registro: " +reader.GetString("id")));


                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Troque o `if` por `while`

```
while (reader.Read())
{
  listBox.Items.Add(("Registro: " +reader.GetString("id")));
}
```